# Trying to join two JSON arrays by item number

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have two JSON files. One includes all product data and the other includes nutritional data. Currently, I am only concatenating both arrays but I need to combine an object from both of these arrays.

In the products JSON file, i have "itemNum" and in the nutritional JSON file i have "itemFullUPC". The number for each product is the same in both of these databases. So "itemFullUPC and "itemNum" will both equal "070796400087" for one particular product in the two databases.

How can I merge these two databases and all the contents in the objects that have "itemNum" and "itemFullUPC" that match? Hope this makes sense.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: 'http://50.73.209.125:8080/api/ItemMaster/',
    success: function(json){
    //assign JSON to product data variable
    product_data = json;

  $.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: 'http://50.73.209.125:8080/api/ItemNutrition/',
    success: function(json){
    //assign JSON to nutrition data variable
    nutritional_data = json;


    var json = product_data.concat(nutritional_data);
    console.log(json);

        }
     });  
   }
});
```

nutritional DB object example

```
{
  "_id":"5791193f8d30bc8e78002ced",
  "itemLastUpdated":"12/9/2016 1:02:31 PM",
  "itemSelenium":0,
  "itemZinc":0,
  "itemMagnesium":0,
  "itemIodine":0,
  "itemPhosphorus":0,
  "itemPanthoAcid":0,
  "itemBiotin":0,
  "itemVitaminB12":0,
  "itemFolate":0,
  "itemVitaminB6":0,
  "itemManga":0,
  "itemNiacin":0,
  "itemRiboflavin":0,
  "itemThiamin":0,
  "itemVitaminK":0,
  "itemVitaminE":0,
  "itemCopper":0,
  "itemVitaminD":0,
  "itemIron":0,
  "itemCalcium":0,
  "itemVitaminC":0,
  "itemVitaminA":0,
  "itemPolyUnsatFat":0,
  "itemSaturFat":0,
  "itemTotalFat":0,
  "itemSugars":0,
  "itemDietFiber":0,
  "itemTotalCarb":1,
  "itemPotassium":0,
  "itemSodium":500,
  "itemCholesterol":0,
  "itemMonoUnsatFat":0,
  "itemTransFat":0,
  "itemProtein":1,
  "itemSugarAlcohol":0,
  "itemCaloriesFromFat":0,
  "itemCalories":5,
  "itemServings":6,
  "itemIngredients":"Chicken Broth, Contains less than 1% of the following: Salt, Dextrose, Monosodium Glutamate, Maltodextrin, Flavor",
  "servingSize":"1 cup",
  "servingSizeUnit":"cup",
  "servingSizeQnty":1,
  "itemNum":"070796400087",
  "__v":0
}
```

product DB object example

```
{
  "_id":"577411f7cce3c4c741000001",
  "itemGMOFree":"N",
  "itemBrandLetter":"C",
  "itemKosherSym":"N",
  "itemShipper":"N",
  "itemRefridge":"N",
  "itemFrozen":"N",
  "itemPreWeight":"Y",
  "itemDeli":"N",
  "itemGlutenFree":"Y",
  "itemHoliday":"N",
  "itemSeasonBuy":"Y",
  "itemScannable":"Y",
  "itemUnlabeled":"N",
  "itemPalletWeight":2500,
  "itemPalletTiers":10,
  "itemPalletBlocks":10,
  "itemCaseCube":0.56,
  "itemCaseDepth":16.25,
  "itemCaseWidth":12,
  "itemCaseHeight":5,
  "itemCaseWeight":24.5,
  "itemCaseUnits":12,
  "itemPieceCube":0.043,
  "itemPieceDepth":4,
  "itemPieceWidth":4,
  "itemPieceHeight":4.65,
  "itemPieceWeight":1.75,
  "itemNetContent":"28.00",
  "itemFullUPC":"070796400087",
  "itemCountry":"Italy",
  "itemPackSize":"12/28 oz",
  "itemUOM":"OZ",
  "itemDescription":"Whole peeled San Marzano plum tomatoes are specially grown at the base of Mt. Vesuvius, and are freshly packed with basil in puree. This type of tomato is sweeter, less acidic, contains less seeds, and has higher pectin than other tomatoes.",
  "itemName":"Cento San Marzano Certified Tomatoes",
  "itemBuildNum":0,
  "itemSuffix":7,
  "itemItem":40008,
  "itemMFG":70796,
  "itemPrefix":0,
  "itemCase_GTIN":30,
  "itemPiece_GTIN":0,
  "imageURL":"http://centogallery.zenfolio.com/img/s5/v130/p961607729-3.jpg",
  "itemCommodity":"1120",
  "__v":0,
  "itemLastUpdated":"12/21/2016 1:06:28 PM",
  "itemVendor":17477,
  "itemBPAFree":"",
  "itemCategory":1,
  "itemDairy":"",
  "itemEgg":"",
  "itemLowSodium":"",
  "itemOrganic":"",
  "itemPeanuts":"",
  "itemShellfish":"",
  "itemSoy":"",
  "itemTreeNuts":"",
  "itemWheat":"",
  "itemWholeGrain":""
}
```

notice how both of these objects both contain the same item number "070796400087". i need to combine both of these examples where the itemNum matches itemsFullUPC.

Comment: Can you post a couple of examples of each JSON construct?

Comment: @VanquishedWombat i put it above ty

Comment: I guess you want to combine so that you do not need to run big loops of array 2 when the user selects a product from array 1 - right?

Comment: yeah and im trying to make it so i can run one loop to pass data to another function. because i need to include the nutritional data for each product too. basically the product DB object example is the item description etc and the nutritional object is that products nutritional facts. i just want to combine them @VanquishedWombat

Comment: Easiest way then would be to process array of objects from JSON string 2 into an associative array. So when user selects a product in array 1 you can use the prod id from it to go direct to the details in array 2. ok ?

Comment: can you show me how i would go about this? i would really appreciate it. but yes your correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131727/discussion-between-vanquished-wombat-and-tom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works by linking your array2 objects to a new JS object by assigning them as properties. Read up on javascript associative arrays for a better understanding.

```js
    // Assuming 2 arrays array1 & array2 - using dummy data here for clarity. Important to note that both have some matching value.

    var array1 = JSON.parse('[{"itemNum": "1234a", "otherParam": "A1"},{"itemNum": "5678a", "otherParam": "B2"}]')

    var array2 = JSON.parse('[{"itemFullUPC": "1234a", "itemDescription": "Details about product 1234a"},{"itemFullUPC": "5678a", "itemDescription": "Details about product 5678a"}]')

   
    // Load phase - run any time after array 2 is loaded
    var lookup = {}
    for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i = i + 1){
        obj = array2[i];
        lookup[obj.itemFullUPC] = obj; // creates a property in lookup object with key of itemFullPC
    }
        
    function getProdDetails(idx){
        var prod = array1[idx]
        console.log("itemDescription for " + prod.itemNum + " = " + lookup[prod.itemNum].itemDescription)
    }

    getProdDetails(1)
    getProdDetails(0)
```